# QCombobox background text color not reflected in selected state

Tags: python, qcombobox

The following code works but doesn't do in full what exactly is needed:

```
nameList = ('John','Tom','Henry','Michelle','Ashish','Jo-Huang', ...)
colorNameList = ('Michelle','Jennifer','Claudia','JimSung', ...)
callBackObj.NameComboBox.clear()
callBackObj.NameComboBox.addItem(QString('Account Names'))
model = callBackObj.NameComboBox.model()
for name in nameList:
    item = PyQt4.QtGui.QStandardItem(str(account))
    if name in colorNameList:
        item.setBackground(PyQt4.QtGui.QColor('red'))
    model.appedRow(item)
```

Now whenever I expand and view the dropdown, the names in colorNameList appear in red background. So far so good. However when I select one of these red-background names they do not show as red-background when left selected.

Any ideas how I can ensure that on selection red items appear red and non-red appears non-red.

Many thanks!

Rahul

Comment: Anybody who can help here please.

Comment: Any comments from PyQt experts.